# How do I change how fast the controls on VLC in full screen mode disappear?

Tags: display, vlc-media-player

When playing video in full screen mode on VLC, I find that the controls get auto-hidden too soon. How can I change the speed at which the controls are hidden?

Answer (score 3):

There is an option in the preferences:

- Tools->Preferences
- Select to show all settings
- Select the "Video" tree item.
- Change the value of the "Hide cursor and fullscreen controller after x milliseconds" to the desired value.

Comment: No. It is not the cursor or fullscreen controller that bothers me. What I mean is the controls that appear when while watching video and I change, lets say, volume. A vertical line appears and disappear in a second or so. This control is what I want to change, how soon it disappear. Is that more clear now? Thank you anyway.

Comment: this may not have solved the author's problem, but it's exactly what I was looking for. I wanted the fullscreen controls to stay there, so I could see my position in the video without moving the mouse.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have any effect when using touch... The controls disappear barely 1 second after I touch the screen, making it hard to use them